# Нормально ли с точки зрения чистоты кода наличие большого количества хелперов?

Tags: c#, рефакторинг, чистый-код

Под хелпером понимается static класс с набором static методов, объединенных между собой какой-то некой тематикой. Непример хелпер по работе с файлами, хелпер по работе с базой и т.п.
У меня очень много подобных хелперов. Делая какую-либо задачу понимаешь, что часть методов повторно где-то еще будут использованы, поэтому они преобразуются в статические и выносятся в хелпер. В итоге получается ситуация, когда по всему солюшену (с множеством проектов внутри) разбросаны разного рода хелперы. Нормально ли такое положение с точки зрения чистоты кода или же так делать плохо? Если плохо, то как делать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Это не очень хорошо, и противоречит принципам [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) которые в свою очередь помогают писать простой, слабосвязанный, легко-расширяемый код, на который можно легко писать юнит тесты.

Гораздо лучше вместо хелперов использовать "сервисы" которые могут быть синглтонами если нужно хранить глобальное состояние. И пробрасывать как зависимость через конструктор.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
    public interface IFileService //Сервис вместо хелпера
    {
        IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string fileName);
    }

    public class FileService : IFileService //Реализация файлового сервиса
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string fileName)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    yield return reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IFileParser
    {
        IEnumerable<decimal> Parse(string fileName);
    }

    public class FileParser : IFileParser//Класс в котором требуется работа с файлами
    {
        private readonly IFileService fileService;

        public FileParser(IFileService fileService)
        {
            this.fileService = fileService;
        }

        public IEnumerable<decimal> Parse(string fileName)
        {
            foreach (var line in fileService.ReadLines(fileName))
                if (decimal.TryParse(line, out var number))
                    yield return number;
        }
    }
```

Так как вы передаете в класс зависимость по интерфейсу, то в некоторых случаях вы можете передавать другую реализацию файлового сервиса, например `XMLFileService` а при юнит тестировании `FileParser` можете передавать сгенерированную заглушку `IFileService`